# BargainFinderMaxVM API prefered Airlines

Tags: sabre

Could somebody advise, if there is a way to pass prefered Airlines to 'BargainFinderMaxVM' Sabre API?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a "VM" version of BFM, but all of its versions work like this:
You could use `<TravelPreferences>
                <VendorPref Code="SX" PreferLevel="Preferred">
                </VendorPref>` but this will be considered by the service as the same as "Only". Another thing you can do is to add a list of carrriers you don't want with something like `<TravelPreferences>
                <VendorPref Code="SX" PreferLevel="Unacceptable"></VendorPref>`. You can keep repeating the VendorPref node with unacceptable carriers until you get the carrier you need. Unfortunately that is how the system works, as Preferred and Only are actually the same.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this too. I am using rest version, so JSON looks like this for 2 preferred airlines for example:

```
   "TravelPreferences": {
      "VendorPref": [{
       "Code": "BA", 
       "PreferLevel": "Preferred"
       },{
       "Code": "AA", 
       "PreferLevel": "Preferred"
       }],
```